# How to restore back the string format after manipulation

Tags: php, regex

I need to extract the sentences or paragraph to each words and manipulate the word into another form. For example, I need to change the word of **'*noodle*'** to **'*##noodle##*'**. I'm using this code to explode the sentence into words and combine back using `implode()` function.

```
function display_sentence_with_answer($str="")
{
    $arr_output = [];
    $str = preg_replace("#<p>(\s| |</?\s?br\s?/)*</?p>#","",$str);
    $words = preg_replace('#<[^>]+>#', ' ', $str);
    $arr_words = preg_split('/<[^>]+>(?:\s+<[^>]+>)*|\s+/u', trim($words));

    foreach($arr_words as $word)
    {
        $arr_output[] = '##'.$word.'##';
    }
    $output_str = implode(" ",$arr_output);
    return $output_str;
}
```

Input:

```
Nyatakan pecahan bagi rajah di bawah.

<br/>
4/5


<p>
p</p>
```

However, I got the output:

```
##Nyatakan## ##pecahan## ##bagi## ##rajah## ##di## ##bawah.## ##4/5## ##p##
```

How to restore back my current input format? Anyone experience this kind of requirements?

My expected output would be:

```
##Nyatakan## ##pecahan## ##bagi## ##rajah## ##di## ##bawah.##

<br/>
##4/5##


<p>
p</p>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could return an array with two elements: original string and processed string.

Comment: @user1915746 Wouldn't really help as he still needs to identify which strings have < or /> in them. he may aswell do the check for that in his original array

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex with PCRE verbs `(*SKIP)(*F)` to skip certain matches:

```
(?:<([^>]*)>.*?</\1>|<[^>]*/>)(*SKIP)(*F)|\b\w\S*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PPpdF8/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
(?:                   # start non capturing group
   <([^>]*)>.*?</\1>  # match a tag and closing tag <tag>...</tag>
   |                  # OR
   <[^>]*/>           # match a tag like <tag/>
)                     # end non capturing group
(*SKIP)(*F)           # skip this match
|                     # OR
\b\w\S*               # match a word starting with a word character
```

**Caution:** HTML is not a regular language, it can be very unpredictable and it is not advisable to parse HTML with regex.

Comment: How to use in PHP?I tried but not success. Can you show me? ;)

Comment: Can you recommend to me, what is the best webpage to practice REGEX?

Comment: This should work in php. In the demo link I provided you can see php code for the same regex.

Comment: For learning regular expressions use http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Hi @anubhava, can you look at this regex? It does not work if I change the input.

https://regex101.com/r/PPpdF8/2

Comment: In your question `Nyatakan pecahan bagi rajah di bawah.` is outside any HTML tag and this answer provides a regex for that. In your example you enclosed same string between `<p>` and `</p>` which makes input completely different from question.

Comment: Yes of course, but I can not expect the input from html. Any tags may come. The samples just from my mind.

Comment: In that case regex is not the right tool since HTML parsing should be done using DOM parser. If you update your question with all the relevant details then I can work on an alternate solution.

Comment: Tq...for DOM parser, if the tag is not complete, then is it may occur any error?I've done this method before.

Comment: For incomplete HTML even regex cannot help you.